# Sending email in livecode

Tags: email, livecode

i am trying to Build a program that will send a default email to an email address , The receiver address will be taken from text field , and the sender address , subject , message will be provided on the code .

I tried this code and i got a problem when it get to " **get shell("echo" && wrapQ(shellEscape(tMsg)) && "| /usr/sbin/sendmail" && ** "

The button send :

```
  on mouseUp
    local tMsg
    put "Been checked" into tMsg
    put "User2@hotmail.com" into pFrom
    put the text of field "emailtext" into pTo
    put "Checked" into pSub
    put "Been checked" into tMsg
    put "Checked" into pSub
    put "From:" && pFrom & return & "To:" && pTo & return & "Subject:" && pSub & \
    return into tMsg    
    get shell("echo" && wrapQ(shellEscape(tMsg)) && "| /usr/sbin/sendmail" && \
    wrapQ(shellEscape(pTo)) && "-f" && wrapQ(shellEscape(pFrom)))
     send mail
      end mouseUp
```

Comment: Which operating sustem are you using? Mac OS X or Linux?

Comment: Should it be one of them ? i am using Window7

Comment: On Windows, /usr/sbin/sendmail probably won't work without installing extra software.
Which error do you get returned?
You might want to use VBScript to send a message through Outlook or Thunderbird.

Comment: I will use revmail , thanks

Comment: OK, but revMail doesn't do the same as what you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "revMail" command. See the dictionary for syntax.

Comment: It could be a possible solution, but this isn't really an answer to the question.